# Trying to respond with text split into array of words from node.js http server

Tags: javascript, node.js

New to node.js, appreciate all the help you can offer. Trying to response out the variable 'words' but when I start the server and go to localhost it crashes and says " TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer" but when I try to write the same variable to the console it works. Thanks for the help!

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
var text = fs.readFileSync("text.txt").toString();
var words = text.split(/\b/);
function start(){
function onRequest(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
    var wordCounts = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = (wordCounts["_" + words[i]] || 0) + 1;
        response.write(words);

    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("server has started");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Comment: `words` (which you pass to `response.write`) is an **Array**, not a string or buffer. What do you want to output, `words[i]` maybe?

Comment: Or, wait, your `write` call isn't in the loop actually. Please fix your weird indentation.

Comment: Thank Bergi! I'm trying to find the most common words from a file. Suggestions?

Comment: So what did you expect your code to do? Try to explain what you wanted to do, and I think you will see your mistakes quite fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
…
var words = text.split(/\s+/); // you hardly want to split on every word boundary
                               // but rather on the spaces in between
…
    var wordCounts = {}; // an object, not a string!
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        wordCounts["_" + words[i]] = (wordCounts["_" + words[i]] || 0) + 1;
    var result = Object.keys(wordCounts).sort(function(a, b) {
        return wordCounts[b]-wordCounts[a];
    }).map(function(w) {
        return w.slice(1)+": "+wordCounts[w];
    }).join("\n");
    response.write(result); // write a string!
…
```

Comment: one more thing... How would I limit this to top common?

Answer (score 1):

The console will have no problem with this, because it will automatically stringify most anything you put into `console.log()`. Try this: `response.write(JSON.stringify(words))`